# post only visible to all other users

Tags: iphone, ios

I have integrated facebook with my app and its connecting well. The problem is that the content which I post is not visible when I am looged into it but my friends can see that news. whats the problem?

```
      NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"123456789", @"app_id",
                                   @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
                                   @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
                                   @"Facebook Dialogs", @"name",
                                   @"Reference Documentation", @"caption",
                                   @"Using Dialogs to interact with users.", @"description",
                                   @"Facebook Dialogs are so easy!",  @"message",
                                   nil];

    [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

replace 1234567 with my app id.what the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

By default Facebook posts items on your wall and your friends can see those posts in their news feed. Have you tried checking your wall or news feed to see if the posts are available there?